# Rotating and Animating an ImageView without any distortion?

Tags: ios, swift, animation

I'm currently trying to rotate an image about 13 degrees and then have that image "dash" off the screen to the left. It's not working the way I'd like -- once the image rotates and I try to animate any more movements it distorts the image by stretching it 'till it's one pixel thin!

How do I preserve the image's width and height without any distortion? I tried layout constraints and programmatically setting the frame.size (width and height) but that didn't work either. Here's the code:

```
 @IBOutlet weak var astro: UIImageView!
 UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.5, animations: {
                    self.astro.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: -13 * 3.14/180.0)
                    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
                }, completion: { (success) in
                    if(success == true){
                        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.5, animations: {
                            self.astro.frame.origin.x = -100
                            self.astro.frame.origin.y = 0
                            self.astro.frame.size.height = 119
                            self.astro.frame.size.width = 108
                        })
                    }
```

Comment: Rotation and translation have nothing to do with image distortion it may happen if you try to scale it !!!

Comment: There's nothing in the code itself that's scaling the image. So pretty much all the rest of my code is in default mode... so how would I just turn off the scaling?

Comment: does it scales when you rotate it , also does width and height values are static like what you do in completion

Comment: the image doesn't distort when it rotates. The distortions occur during every animation that happens after the rotation.  The width and height I set in the completion block don't seem to have any effect what-so-ever, that was my futile attempt at trying to prevent the image from distorting.

Comment: Same width and height values in storyboard as completion ????

Comment: oh, yes. that's exactly what the values are based off of.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162926/discussion-between-karmadeli-and-sh-khan).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to "reset" the transform, change the frame, and then re-apply the transform:

```
    let rot = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: -13 *  3.14/180.0)

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.5, animations: {
        self.astro.transform = rot
    }, completion: { (success) in
        if success == true {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.5, animations: {
                self.astro.transform = .identity
                self.astro.frame.origin.x = -100.0
                self.astro.transform = rot
            })
        }
    })
```